# Optimize spark dataframe operation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark(version-2.4) dataframe of the pattern.

```
+----------+
| ColumnA  |
+----------+
| 1000@Cat |
| 1001@Dog |
| 1000@Cat |
| 1001@Dog |
| 1001@Dog |
+----------+
```

I am conditionally applying a regex removal of the number that is appended to the string using the following code

```
dataset.withColumn("ColumnA",when(regexp_extract(dataset.col("ColumnA"), "\\@(.*)", 1)
                                                    .equalTo(""), dataset.col("ColumnA"))
                                               .otherwise(regexp_extract(dataset.col("ColumnA"), "\\@(.*)", 1)));
```

which would result a dataframe in the following format

```
+---------+
| ColumnA |
+---------+
| Cat     |
| Dog     |
| Cat     |
| Dog     |
| Dog     |
+---------+
```

This runs correctly and produces the desired output.

However the regexp_extract operation is being applied twice, once to check if the returned string is empty and if not then reapply the regexp_extract on the column.

Is there any optimization that can be done on this code to make it perform better.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` function instead of `regexp_extract`.

Please check below code with execution time

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------+
|columna |
+--------+
|1000@Cat|
|1001@Dog|
|1000@Cat|
|1001@Dog|
|1001@Dog|
+--------+


scala> spark.time(df.withColumn("parsed",split($"columna","@")(1)).show(false))
+--------+------+
|columna |parsed|
+--------+------+
|1000@Cat|Cat   |
|1001@Dog|Dog   |
|1000@Cat|Cat   |
|1001@Dog|Dog   |
|1001@Dog|Dog   |
+--------+------+

Time taken: 14 ms

scala> spark.time { df.withColumn("ColumnA",when(regexp_extract($"columna", "\\@(.*)", 1).equalTo(""), $"columna").otherwise(regexp_extract($"columna", "\\@(.*)", 1))).show(false) }
+-------+
|ColumnA|
+-------+
|Cat    |
|Dog    |
|Cat    |
|Dog    |
|Dog    |
+-------+

Time taken: 22 ms

scala>
```

`contains` function to check `@` value in column

```
scala> spark.time(df.withColumn("parsed",when($"columna".contains("@"), lit(split($"columna","@")(1))).otherwise("")).show(false))
+--------+------+
|columna |parsed|
+--------+------+
|1000@Cat|Cat   |
|1001@Dog|Dog   |
|1000@Cat|Cat   |
|1001@Dog|Dog   |
|1001@Dog|Dog   |
+--------+------+

Time taken: 14 ms
```